# Substrings in Python. Copies in memory?

Tags: python, regex, string, immutability

Say I have a string `my_string` in Python and that I tokenize it according to `some_pattern`:

```
match.re.search(some_pattern, my_string)
string_1 = match.group(1)
string_2 = match.group(2)
....
```

Are `string_1` and `string_2` ("deep") copies of the substrings in `my_string` or references to the same location in memory? Do `string_1` and `string_2` allocate memory for full copies of the characters in `my_string`?

Please note that I am **not asking about the immutability** of the strings. If `my_string` is *very long*, I would like to know what is the hit in **memory** that I take by tokenizing my strings.

I don't need to know exactly how much memory is re-used, but it would certainly be useful to know if a tokenization of a string ends up duplicating memory.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please note that I am not asking about the immutability of the strings, I know that strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Keep in mind you're asking about a very specif implementation detail which may change between python versions and will have at least subtle differences between python implementations.

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the Python 2.7.3 source code, taking a slice of a string makes a copy of the character data:

`Objects/stringobject.c`:

`string_slice()` calls the following function, `PyString_FromStringAndSize()`:

```
/* Inline PyObject_NewVar */
op = (PyStringObject *)PyObject_MALLOC(PyStringObject_SIZE + size);
if (op == NULL)
    return PyErr_NoMemory();
PyObject_INIT_VAR(op, &PyString_Type, size);
op->ob_shash = -1;
op->ob_sstate = SSTATE_NOT_INTERNED;
if (str != NULL)
    Py_MEMCPY(op->ob_sval, str, size);
op->ob_sval[size] = '\0';
```

Here, `str` is a pointer to the character data, and `size` is the length. Note the malloc and the memcpy.

Different Python implementations (and indeed different versions of CPython) might behave differently. For example, Jython probably uses [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), which doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Another hint is the [python-c-api-reference](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html): there is now way to contruct a *view* on the data of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in python, so the substrings nothing but new objects.

```
In [7]: str="foobar"

In [8]: id(str)
Out[8]: 140976032

In [10]: id(str[:4])
Out[10]: 141060224
```

The only case where the substring object returned is same as the original string object is when the `string==substring`:

```
In [16]: foo="foobar"

In [17]: id(foo)
Out[17]: 140976032

In [18]: id(foo[:])
Out[18]: 140976032

In [19]: foo="foobar"*10000   # huge string

In [20]: id(foo)
Out[20]: 141606344

In [21]: id(foo[:])
Out[21]: 141606344
```

Comment: One doesn't follow from the other. In Java, strings are immutable, yet substrings refer to the original string's storage.

Comment: As @NPE mentioned, I am not asking about the immutability of the strings. I know they are immutable.  Please see my note in the OP.

Comment: @user273158 a substring is always results in a new object in python, but in case of some small strings you might see some caching done by python internally, but for that the substring returned should be equal to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable, so the distinction isn't that meaningful in this case, but they are copies.  Nothing you can do to `string_1` and `string_2` will affect the contents of `my_string`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking about the immutability of the strings. I know they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it helps much or even answers your question, but you could use `finditer` and then slice the original string only on demand...

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'abcdefhijkl'
>>> matches = list(re.finditer('.' , string))
>>> dir(matches[0])
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'end', 'endpos', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 'lastindex', 'pos', 're', 'regs', 'span', 'start', 'string']
>>> matches[0].span()
(0, 1)
```

and then go from there...